# Apache not able to restart

Tags: apache2, reboot

Trying to restart apache from terminal using the following command:

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

When executing that command, I'm getting below error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

On excuting "systemctl status apache2.service" I get this output:

```
apache2.service - (null)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2015-05-30 02:22:41 IST; 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4866 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Apache `error.log`:

```
AH00489: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd'
```

Comment: after you run the apache2 restart and get that error,  run `sudo journalctl -xe` that will give you a better idea about what happened. if you still have issues understanding it. Post the results here.

Comment: ok. That didn't help me either. What is in the apache log files. `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @grag42 thanks for your suggestion, I ran sudo journalctl -xe and found some rewrite rule issue was there and fixed it and its running now.

Comment: Thats good to hear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache not starting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/644970/apache-not-starting)

Comment: @rancho: What leads you to believe the question is a duplicate? The linked question contains a quite specific error message which we don't have here. The possible causes for OP's issue a pretty unclear at this moment.

Comment: In my case case port 80 was taken, so I had to shut it down, `sudo fuser 80/tcp -l` , after this I was able to start apache

Answer (score 132):

There is some syntax error in the file `apache2.conf`.

In a terminal, type:

```
cd /etc/apache2
```

Then:

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

It will show you where is the error in the `apache2.conf` file to correct.

Comment: great approach tnx, saved my time

Comment: This is fantastic.

Comment: Thanks. Was a problem with redmine and PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot option.

Comment: lol, after execute: `apache2ctl configtest` got syntax ok, but when i run `apache2 --help` got `apache2: Syntax error on line 82 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot`  and no errors in apache  error.log !

Comment: after see closely to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` dir, i noticed, that i got file, not symbolic linc to site.conf +  reenable mod php5.6 (sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6) my service apache2 has been started without  "ohh-ahh"

Comment: Thanks for this technique. In my PC, the problem was that the log directory of Apache2 in /var/log/ directory was missing. Once I recreated the directory using `mkdir /var/log/apache2`, it didn't complain anymore.

Comment: Thanks, that was a life-saver.

Comment: Thanks saved My lot of time

Comment: You may need to run this with `sudo` or its output may be a bit misleading.

Comment: The error was due to the line :`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` which includes an empty file, so I've commented it and everything is OK now

Comment: worked like a charm.+1

Answer (score 89):

Maybe this will help to find the cause:

```
journalctl | tail
```

In my case it was a mistake in the configuration file:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain-wsf.lan.conf
```

Comment: `No journal files were found.`

Comment: @StevieG, try `sudo journalctl | tail`

Comment: What did you do to fix the thing?

Comment: in my case, i also did a mistake in the apache2.config file

Comment: Thanks. I wrong typed my directory for my newly added site conf.

Answer (score 40):

The problem is because some configuration files are deleted, you have to reinstall it.

REINSTALL APACHE2:

To replace configuration files that have been deleted, without purging the package, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apache2
```

To fully remove the apache2 config files, you should:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

which will then let you reinstall it in the usual way with:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Purge is required to remove all the config files - if you delete the config files but only remove the package, then this is remembered & missing config files are not reinstalled by default.

Then REINSTALL PHP5:

```
apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5 php5 && \
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

Comment: Why do you think some configuration files were deleted?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `purge`! This one fixed my issues with apache2 not running: `$ sudo apt purge apache2 && sudo apt install apache2`

Comment: This works for me. Genius!

Answer (score 6):

Problem:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Solution:

- To fully remove the apache2 config files, you should:

  1) `sudo apt-get purge apache2`
- which will then let you reinstall it in the usual way with:

  2) `sudo apt-get install apache2`

==> It Works fine...

thanks....

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error after removing a virtual host. The problem was the lingering SSL conf file associated with that host located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. The SSL was through Let's Encrypt so the code for me to remove was:

```
sudo rm yourdomain.com-le-ssl.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

you most likely have a syntax error. for me it was in my 'sites-enabled' folder.

i mis-spelled 'ServerAlias' to 'ServerAlisa'.

Comment: Mine was I misspelled my folder.

Answer (score 2):

I got the Same errors While working with .htaccess

I just put this command

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` this folder

after adding this i have getting the error

then i delete these peace of command from the file and my error has resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a configuration error. I just now had an old site enabled on apache, what caused this error. So I had to disable it before reloading apache.

```
sudo a2dissite <my-site>
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help! I was able to install correctly with Solution:

To fully remove the apache2 config files, you should:

1. `sudo apt-get purge apache2`
   which will then let you reinstall it in the usual way with:
2. `sudo apt-get install apache 2`

It now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have some site enabled but you deleted its configuration file. Try disabling the site with
    sudo a2dissite "name"
and then restart apache server. At least this was the problem for me and this action solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error started to appear after doing `apt upgrade`. After playing a lot I went to following directories to see what I can disable.

- /etc/apache2/mods-enabled - `a2dismod`  (to turn back on `a2enconf`)
- /etc/apache2/conf-enabled - `a2disconf`   (to turn back on `a2enconf`)

In my case, I had to those MODS enabled.

[image]

It seems that `apt-upgrade` must have removed/broken php7.2 because as soon as I disabled it and restarted everything worked. Of course, in anyone else's case, it may be something different. When Apache crashes it may be bad config or bad mod. You have to pick your battles.

Answer (score 1):

For what it may be relevant at this stage, but today I came across the same problem and it turned out to be an issue with the certificate file.

So eventually the config was all ok, but in uploading the new .crt content I did in the wrong file, meaning there were no more matching for a particular site and the whole server was refusing to start.

No indication of incorrect SSL certificate in the log or anywhere else, which took me a while to figure out.