# Apache not starting

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

So I tried to start my apache2 server with the following command...

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

But then I get this error message...

```
Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So when I try and see the systemctl, I get this...

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-07-06 10:34:49 IST; 4min 23s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8899 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)

Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 apache2[8899]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 apache2[8899]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 apache2[8899]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 systemd[1]: apache2.service failed.
```

http://localhost/ on my browser also gives me an error which means apache is not running.

When I do this...

```
sudo restart apache2
```

I get this error...

```
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Somebody please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vivid - failed to connect to upstart: connection refused](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614970/vivid-failed-to-connect-to-upstart-connection-refused)

Comment: This can also happen if you have error in configuration files like apache2.conf...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for some reason you deleted envvars config file

```
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 apache2[8899]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 06 10:34:49 archisman-HP-ProBook-440-G2 apache2[8899]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
```

So you have to create it and paste the content from [here](http://pastebin.com/AHhRyVek) (default content for this file)

```
sudo touch /etc/apache2/envvars
sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Then restart apache service as usual

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I made changes in `apache.conf file` for some reason, which leads me to the same error as you.

I have reinstalled Apache server, now everything is working fine.

Use the following commands:

1. Uninstall Apache:

   ```
    sudo apt-get remove apache2*
   ```
2. Install Apache

   ```
    sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
3. Restart server

   ```
    sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
4. If you see an error "no listening sockets available, shutting down"
   please change port to 8080 or different ports under /etc/apache2/ports.conf file, this might be due to TCP port 80 being already in use by another program.

Comment: @arnaudbey: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/662382/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Without checking log file direct suggesting someone to remove and reinstall apache2 might bring huge data loss to someone.