# Apache2 does not reload/restart (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 error)

Tags: server, apache2

The error which is showing is:

```
Failed to reload apache2.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by 
any .service files See system logs and 'systemctl status apache2.service' for details.
```

I have run the following two commands, and here are the logs returned, respectively:

```
systemctl status apache2.service
journalctl -xe
```

Logs:

`systemctl status apache2.service`

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-02-21 18:41:29 IST; 33min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14374 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 14396 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─14414 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─14417 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─14418 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

`journalctl -xe`

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Feb 21 18:41:28 oxygen apache2[14396]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Feb 21 18:41:28 oxygen apache2[14396]: [Tue Feb 21 18:41:28.950705 2017] [core:error] [pid 14413:tid 140406115329920] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could n
Feb 21 18:41:28 oxygen apache2[14396]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 45.56.70.225. Set the 'ServerName'
Feb 21 18:41:29 oxygen apache2[14396]:  *
Feb 21 18:41:29 oxygen systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit apache2.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 21 18:41:48 oxygen sudo[14475]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/a2ensite indiairapp.com.cong
Feb 21 18:41:48 oxygen sudo[14475]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Feb 21 18:41:48 oxygen sudo[14475]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 18:41:51 oxygen sudo[14480]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/a2ensite indiairapp.com.conf
Feb 21 18:41:51 oxygen sudo[14480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Feb 21 18:41:51 oxygen sudo[14480]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 18:45:01 oxygen CRON[14492]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 18:45:01 oxygen CRON[14493]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 21 18:45:01 oxygen CRON[14492]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 18:47:01 oxygen CRON[14495]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 18:47:01 oxygen CRON[14496]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 21 18:47:01 oxygen CRON[14495]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 18:55:01 oxygen CRON[14498]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 18:55:01 oxygen CRON[14499]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 21 18:55:01 oxygen CRON[14498]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 18:58:59 oxygen sudo[14518]:  nauman3 : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/etc/apache2/sites-available ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/indiairapp.conf
Feb 21 18:58:59 oxygen sudo[14518]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by nauman3(uid=0)
Feb 21 19:00:45 oxygen sudo[14518]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 19:00:49 oxygen sudo[14520]:  nauman3 : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/etc/apache2/sites-available ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/a2ensite indiairapp.conf
Feb 21 19:00:49 oxygen sudo[14520]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by nauman3(uid=0)
Feb 21 19:00:49 oxygen sudo[14520]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 19:05:01 oxygen CRON[14534]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 19:05:01 oxygen CRON[14535]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 21 19:05:01 oxygen CRON[14534]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 19:15:01 oxygen CRON[14547]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 19:15:01 oxygen CRON[14548]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 21 19:15:01 oxygen CRON[14547]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 32):

It's a permission issue with the `apache server` the `systemctl` command should be run with `root` privileges:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

> sudo apache2ctl configtest

This should give you a better idea of the current issues.

(Possibly related: [Apache not able to restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629995/apache-not-able-to-restart))

Comment: Yes, when i ran this command i came to know "Unknown Authn provider: ldap" from this information i am able to solve the issue